# Data from firebase is coming in a shuffled manner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am trying to populate a table with data coming from firestore collection. The data is coming perfectly but when I am console logging that the data is coming in a shuffled manner for every row. Let me show you how I want and how it is coming.

Suppose I have 4 documents in the collection `ABC` with keys as `_name, _contact, _comments`.

**Predicted output:**

```
{
  { _name: 'ABC', _contact: 'xyz', _comment: 'def' },
  { _name: 'ABC', _contact: 'xyz', _comment: 'def' },
  { _name: 'ABC', _contact: 'xyz', _comment: 'def' },
  { _name: 'ABC', _contact: 'xyz', _comment: 'def' }
}
```

**Actual Output coming:**

```
{
  { _name: 'ABC', _contact: 'xyz', _comment: 'def' },
  { _contact: 'xyz', _name: 'ABC', _comment: 'def' },
  { _name: 'ABC', _comment: 'def', _contact: 'xyz' },
  { _name: 'ABC', _contact: 'xyz', _comment: 'def' }
}
```

**JS Code**

```
const tableObj = document.getElementById('quoteVal');
dbref.get().then(snap => {
    snap.forEach(item => {
        data = item.data();
        let ele = document.createElement('tr');
        for(let key in data) {
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                ele.innerHTML += '<td>' + data[key] + '</td>';
            }
        }
        tableObj.append(ele);
    });
});
```

Please help me out. I am not understanding why this is happening as I am new to firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should not depend on the order of iteration of fields in a document.  **There is no guaranteed ordering**.

If you require an order, you should sort the fields yourself prior to generating output.